# Latest image_view in ROS Fuerte is now expecting RGB rather than BGR

Tags: ros-fuerte, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a cv_bridge::CvImage image of type '8UC3'.  This publishes a cv::Mat of type BGR.  I have old bag files with image topics published this way.  Up until yesterday these displayed fine.  Today, when visualising with image_view, red is now blue, blue is now red.  However, when I display a live stream using the *exact* same code, the colours are as they should be.

It thus seems that image_transport has changed from images outputting BGR format to RGB.  As I can see no positive benefits for this change, and with the added inconvenience of breaking old bag files, is this a bug?  It seems very much like a case of "If it isn't broken, don't fix it"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42578/latest-image_view-in-ros-fuerte-is-now-expecting-rgb-rather-than-bgr/) by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-08-29**:
I'll cook up a test case to verify.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-08-29**:
I created a test case here: https://gist.github.com/3515031  This creates an image with a Blue-Green-Red-Black pattern, which is then opened in an OpenCV image.  Opening with image_view provides the same result.  Perhaps try this test case and see if it works for you?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-29**:
Could you post the encoding value for the output sensor_msgs/Image messages in your bag?

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2012-08-30**:
@Eric Perko
It seems you're on the right track.  Using rostopic echo from my old bag file I have

format: jpeg

But in the new bag files I have

format: 8UC3; jpeg compressed

These were recorded using the *exact* same code, and so should be identical.  Clearly they're not.

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2012-08-30**:
@mjcarroll
Thanks for the help. The problem only exists in images recorded in *old* bag files (prior to the day of this post) when displayed in *new* image_view / rviz.  Whether it's gone from BGR->RGB or from RGB->BGR I'm not sure, but it has definitely been changed.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-30**:
It seems you are looking at the wrong topic... sensor_msgs/Image (http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) doesn't have a "format" field, only an encoding field. Could you post a old and new bagfile somewhere so that we can download and take a look at it?

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2012-09-02**:
I am actually using compressed images, which do have the format field.  I assumed the message format would be the same but it seems not:

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2012-09-02**:
I am actually using compressed images, which do have the format field.  I assumed the message format would be the same but it seems not:
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug should be fixed in r40039.

https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros-pkg/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2F&view=rev&revision=40039

An updated image_transport_plugin stack has been released. Please let me know if the fix works.

---

Originally posted by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) with karma: 146 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0